# Resource is not found in case of 2 dispatcher servlets

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

In my web.xml I have the following mapping:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>admin</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>admin</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

which is for admin part of my application.

However, when I add another mapping for the metrics:

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>metrics</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>metrics</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/metrics/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and try to reach the resource using for example /metrics/errors url, I get an error that resources is not found. For the resource I have the following controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/metrics")
public class MetricsController  {

@Autowired
private MetricsService metricsService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/errors", method = RequestMethod.GET)

public List<TransactionsPerDay> fetchResult(@RequestParam("startDate") @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd") Date startDate, @RequestParam("endDate") @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd") Date endDate) {

  //Specific logic here 


}
```

Could it be an issue because I try to use 2 Dispatcher servlets in my app? 
When I move my controller inside an admin package, which is covered by admin servlet, the resource suddenly becomes found.

Comment: Is it reachable by URL `/metrics/metrics/errors`? If yes, then remove `@RequestMapping("/metrics")` from `MetricsController`.

Comment: It was reachable by  `/metrics/metrics/errors `, when I removed the mapping from `MetricsController` it is now reachable by metrics/errors. Though I wonder on which ground the first `/metrics` is added to the resource URL ?

Comment: First `/metrics` where added by `<url-pattern>` of `metrics` servlet.

Answer (score 0):

URL is assembled from the following parts:
- `url-pattern` of `DispatcherServlet`
- class-level `@RequestMapping` annotation
- method-level `@RequestMapping` annotation

In our case `MetricsController.fetchResult` is reachable by URL `/metrics/metrics/error`. To make it available by `/metrics/error` I suggest to remove class-level `@RequestMapping` annotation.